# Получить город, зная IP

Tags: ip, javascript, php

Есть страница, в определённом месте которой записан IP-адрес текущего посетителя. Возможно ли, не имея возможности использовать PHP, узнать город посетителя по IP-адресу и вывести его на страницу?

Comment: [Проверка IP по стране и вывод](http://hashcode.ru/questions/15771/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-ip-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ru.smart-ip.net/geoip-api
Можно просто послать на апи
http://ru.smart-ip.net/geoip-json/ВАШ_IP

Comment: Спасибо, именно то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно использовать AJAX. Послать в php скрипту айпишник, а в самом сценарии обработчика использовать библиотеку Geo IP ([Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.geoip.php))

Answer (score 0):

Нет, без какого-либо скриптового языка тут не обойтись. И я что-то понять не могу - каким это способом у вас получается "записать в определённом месте IP-адрес текущего посетителя"?

Comment: **записан** IP-адрес текущего посетителя

Comment: @AlexWindHope Ну, так для того чтоб записать текущего пользователя, надо или вручную его записывать (что полный бред), или использовать, опять таки, какой-то язык.

Comment: @Deonis, сайт размещен на хостинге, который не даёт доступа к `php`, но при этом есть некие теги, которые дают информацию, например тот же `ip`-адрес. А задача заключается в том, что-бы, используя из даного сайтом `ip`-адреса узнать город.

Comment: В таком случае хостинг лучше менять, на самом деле)